# How can I use a file as the commit message in Git?

Tags: linux, git

How can I use a file as the commit message in Git?

I write my message in the file `message`, and I want to use it as the commit message while I executing `git commit -a`.

I tried:

```sh
$ git commit -a -m | cat message
$ cat message | git commit -a -m
$ git commit -a --message=`cat message`
$ cat message > git commit -a -m
$ cat message | git commit -a -m
```

But none of them works.

So is there anybody can solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: [`git commit -a -F message`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--Fltfilegt)

Comment: You really should read the manual `git help commit` before asking SO.

Comment: @phd It works forme, Thanks!

Comment: @Inigo Sorry, I'll be careful next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way . . .

```
git commit -F filename
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: And I like this one better

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to use option `-t some-file`

```
git commit -t some-template-file
```

Answer (score -3):

run the following command

```
cat message | xargs git commit -m
```